# Archivo .java dañado no me aparece mi codigo

Tags: java, xml, archivo, utf-8

Estaba programando y copié mi proyecto a un USB, pero cuando lo abrí en otra computadora esta ya no me abre bien los archivos `.java` y ya no puedo ver mi código, he intentado con varios `IDE`.

Me aparece el siguiente código cuando accedo:

```
%PDF-1.6
%????
1 0 obj<</Count 16/Type/Pages/Kids[55 0 R 54 0 R 56 0 R]>>
endobj
2 0 obj<</Metadata 158 0 R/AcroForm 73 0 R/Pages 1 0 R/Type/Catalog>>
endobj
3 0 obj<</CreationDate(D:20070312141935Z)/Producer(PDFXC Library \(version 2.5\).)/ModDate(D:20070517142432+01'00')/OSInfo(vis: 148; ver: 5.0; bn: 00000893; platf: 2; CDS: Service Pack 4)>>
endobj
4 0 obj<</StemV 78/FontName/Arial/Flags 32/MaxWidth 2000/Descent -212/FontBBox[-665 -325 2000 1006]/Ascent 905/CapHeight 716/XHeight 519/Type/FontDescriptor/ItalicAngle 0/Leading 150/MissingWidth 278/AvgWidth 441/StemH 78>>
endobj
5 0 obj<</Subtype/TrueType/FontDescriptor 4 0 R/LastChar 169/Widths[278 0 0 556 0 0 667 0 333 333 0 0 278 333 278 278 556 556 556 556 556 556 556 556 556 556 278 0 0 584 0 0 0 667 667 722 722 667 611 778 722 278 0 667 556 833 722 778 667 0 722 667 611 722 667 944 0 667 0 0 0 0 0 556 0 556 556 500 556 556 278 556 556 222 222 500 222 833 556 556 556 556 333 500 278 556 500 722 500 500 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 556 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 737]/BaseFont/Arial/FirstChar 32/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding/Type/Font>>
```

Comment: Eso es un .pdf, no un .java...